# Merging selectors from mixins

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I'm trying to contain general styles/tricks in a separate mixin file which can be applied to any project when they're needed. Some of these styles require multiple elements to work together in order to work.

For example:

```
_mixins.scss
====================
@mixin footer_flush_bottom {
    html {
        height: 100%;
    }

    body {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }

    #footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}

main.scss
====================
@import "mixins";

@include footer_flush_bottom;

html {
    background-color: $bg;
    //More stuff
}

body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    //More stuff
}

footer.scss
====================
#footer {
    height: 40px;
}
```

As it is, the mixin works but the generated css separates the mixin from the main code, even when their selectors are the same. The downside to this is ugly css and larger file size when I start including more of these.

```
/* line 14, ../../sass/modules/_mixins.scss */
html {
  height: 100%; }

/* line 18, ../../sass/modules/_mixins.scss */
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative; }

/* line 22, ../sass/modules/_mixins.scss */
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; }

/* line 19, ../../sass/modules/main.scss */
html {
  overflow-y: scroll; }

/* line 37, ../../sass/modules/main.scss */
body {
  margin: 0 auto;

/* line 1, ../sass/modules/footer.scss */
#footer {
  height: 40px;
```

Is there anyway I can do this so that same selectors can be merged? Like this:

```
/* line 19, ../../sass/modules/main.scss */
html {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll; }

/* line 37, ../../sass/modules/main.scss */
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;

/* line 1, ../sass/modules/footer.scss */
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe the selectors can be merged. I wouldn't worry too much about it, GZIP will squish the file size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Sass has no way of merging selectors (this could be considered undesirable, as it would alter the ordering of the selectors).

The only thing you can really do is something like this (or write 2 separate mixins):

```
@mixin footer_flush_bottom {
    height: 100%;

    body {
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        @content;
    }
}

html {
    // additional html styles
    @include footer_flush_bottom {
        // additional body styles
    }
}
```

Comment: I wrote the mixin with the intent of making it pluggable. Writing separate mixins or using an 'if' condition within the mixin would require me to call the mixins in each selector, which kind of defeats its purpose. To add another layer of complexity, I can't do it your way because the next part of the code - #footer - is in its separate file. Perhaps I should add that in the question.