# Any way to separate only specific properties in scss?

Tags: css, sass

While working with scss, I want to keep all the color and background properties separate from my other styling. Here's an example of what I want.

**scss:**

```
.mydiv {
    .menu {
        a {
            display: block;
            line-height: 2;
            background-color: $my_red;
            color: $my_white;
        }
    }
    .insidediv {
        display: block;
        width: 50%;
        float: right;
        background-color: $my_red;
        color: $my_white;
    }
}
```

Want the output like this in **css:**

```
.mydiv .menu a {
    display: block;
    line-height: 2;
}

.mydiv .insidediv {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

.mydiv .menu a,
.mydiv .insidediv {
    background-color: $my_red;
    color: $my_white;
}
```

See, I want every selector that have the property with same value, merge together. So, it would be easy to make color variation without compiling again.

Comment: "it would be easy to make color variation without compiling again" - please, for your own sake, don't do that. You end up with .css that doesn't match the original .scss. Then you'll make some other change to the .scss, recompile, and lose the color changes. Seriously, just limit your edits to the .scss, and live with the occasional recompilation.

Comment: it's for wordpress theme. The theme should have full control on colors. so need to do the css like that.

Comment: If recompiling is a problem, then why are you using SCSS? Maybe you should look into [LiveReload](http://livereload.com/) or alternative solutions like this. Or maybe if you're using Chrome look at [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors)

Comment: Oh, you're working with Wordpress... How about [this](https://kovshenin.com/2014/color-options-vs-decisions/)? It seems to says some things about how to use customisable Wordpress colours with Sass.

Comment: Also related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451296/merging-selectors-from-mixins

Comment: This question is not duplicate. I have searched on stack exchange and google as well. Found nothing about it.
The question marked as duplicate, is not what I want. please look at my question again and you guis will understand. I don't want to combine nested selectors but the selectors that have certain properties with same value.