# Same selector across SASS Partials not being aggregated

Tags: css, sass

I have the same CSS selector across multiple SASS partials files that are all being called into the same master file. Please see example below:

File1:

```
.mySelector { color: #ffffff; }
```

File2:

```
.mySelector { line-height: 1; }
```

Master file:

```
@import 'partials/File1';
@import 'partials/File2';
```

I would have expected SASS to have been clever and found that the same selector is being used in two partial files and combine them for the final single CSS file. Instead it creates two different instances of the same selector in the final file.

I know the SASS architecture I am using might be better managed to accommodate for this but is there a setting or some other mechanism to allow SASS to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging selectors from mixins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451296/merging-selectors-from-mixins)

Comment: I am trying to do a similar thing with Sass. I know that there is [@extend](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend) keyword, but that does not do aggregation as you want it. I too seem to be organising Sass files in a similar manner:  declared different aspects in separate partials. That could be done by making use of custom properties and Sass variables where appropriate and limiting fragmenting of declaration of a selector in multiple partials, but maybe there is a better solution I should be aware of...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for would actually be incorrect behavior, because in a CSS file rule order matters. Take the following code:

```
.foo {
  color: 'red';
}
.bar {
  color: 'blue';
  line-height: 1;
}
.foo {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

You can't merge the two rules for the `.foo` selector, because wherever you'd put the result, it'd never keep the intended styling for elements with both `foo` and `bar` classes.

Comment: Point well taken.

Comment: Chosen as accepted answer because of code illustration in the example and use case where a single element has both classes.

Answer (score 0):

As I remember SASS has no functionality for merging same selectors. 
I think you just need to rewrite your code.

Isn't it logical that there is only one place in one file where you need to adjust something to a specific item? For example if someone else need to change your code that person need to look at two places.

Comment: DRY, and kinda of like normalization for a DB. Yes.